# get Slice Number from 4D dicom tages

Tags: c++, image-processing, dicom, itk

I have 4D DCE images and already wrote a code to order and make 3d images from 4D dicom images, for sorting of images, I used acquisition number from dicom tags and divide total number of slices to got slice number, but in two of my data the acquisition number is not true(don't know why). So when I look at 3D image, it is one and half of normal image. I am thinking to use slice number tags directly( 0054,0081) but because I have 3d images, my program just crash during debugging. Do you have any idea how to use that? 
any other ideas for achieving slice number are well com.

Cheers,
Nady

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with 4D Dicoms, however with 3D dicom it's better to use Patient Position rather than slice number. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598664/1136458 and also http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/insight-users/2005-September/014711.html could be useful

From your question it's not very clear how you have used the acquisition number. Could Number of Frames (0028,0008) and Frame Increment Pointer (0028,0009) be used in your case? I found their definition here http://nipy.org/nibabel/dicom/dicom_fields.html#multi-frame-images