# AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'SliceLocation'

Tags: python, pydicom

I am using below code I got from some articles.

```
def load_patient(files):       
    slices = [pydicom.dcmread(s) for s in files]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))

    try:
        ## actual property is ImagePositionPatient, shortened for screen width ##
        thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImgPosPatient[2] - slices[1].ImgPosPatient[2])
    except:
        thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)

    for s in slices:
        s.SliceThickness = thickness

    return slices
```

Got below error

> AttributeError : 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'SliceLocation'

at

> File : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py
>
> Line : 524,
>
> Func.Name : **getattr**,
>
> Message : return super(Dataset, self).**getattribute**(name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here:
[DICOM Standard](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.2.html#table_C.7-10)
 The Slice Location attribute is optional. The error that is thrown means that there is no such attribute. So in terms of the DICOM standard, receiving this error can be expected.

Comment: So How to generate coronal and saggital view?

Comment: https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/auto_examples/image_processing/reslice.html

Comment: I mean if there is no sliceLocation attribute. Will it be okay to sort the dcm by number sequence and then do it?

Comment: I presume you mean instance number, and for clinical purposes that is NOT a good measure for ordering your slices unfortunately. Well explained, and how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598664/2878353